# What steps can I take to troubleshoot and fix errors when trying to run an assembly language program on DOS BOX?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, masm, dosbox

code error

[image]

proteus program

[image]

Need help to fix the code because I want to run that code in program 'Analog to Digital Conversion using 8086 microprocessor and here I don't get the proper output as DOS BOX not able to link the object file to executable fie as it has errors in the following code;

```
DATA SEGMENT
 PORTA EQU 00H
 PORTB EQU 02H
 PORTC EQU 04H
 PORT_CON EQU 06H
DATA ENDS
CODE SEGMENT
 MOV AX,DATA
 MOV DS, AX

ORG 0000H
START:

 MOV DX, PORT_CON
 MOV AL, 10010000B
 OUT DX, AL

 MOV AL,00H

   
XX:
 MOV DX,PORTA
 IN AL,DX
 MOV DX, PORTC
 OUT DX,AL
 MOV DX, PORTB
 MOV AL, 00000000B
 OUT DX,AL

 MOV cx, 0ffH
D1: LOOP D1
   MOV DX, PORTB
 MOV AL, 00000001B
 OUT DX,AL
          
           MOV cx, 0ffH
D2: LOOP D2
 JMP XX

CODE ENDS
END
```

Here's the Assembler LST file hope this thing helps solving

```
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 5.00                  1/5/23 20:55:25
                                                             Page     1-1


       1 0000               DATA SEGMENT 
       2 = 0000              PORTA EQU 00H 
       3 = 0002              PORTB EQU 02H 
       4 = 0004              PORTC EQU 04H 
       5 = 0006              PORT_CON EQU 06H 
       6 0000               DATA ENDS 
       7 0000               CODE SEGMENT 
       8 0000  B8 ---- R         MOV AX,DATA 
       9 0003  8E D8             MOV DS, AX 
      10                 
      11 0000               ORG 0000H 
      12 0000               START: 
adc.asm(12): error A2062: Missing or unreachable CS
      13                 
      14 0000  BA 0006           MOV DX, PORT_CON 
      15 0003  B0 90             MOV AL, 10010000B 
      16 0005  EE            OUT DX, AL 
      17                 
      18 0006  B0 00             MOV AL,00H 
      19                 
      20                    
      21 0008               XX: 
adc.asm(21): error A2062: Missing or unreachable CS
      22 0008  BA 0000           MOV DX,PORTA 
      23 000B  EC            IN AL,DX 
      24 000C  BA 0004           MOV DX, PORTC 
      25 000F  EE            OUT DX,AL 
      26 0010  BA 0002           MOV DX, PORTB 
      27 0013  B0 00             MOV AL, 00000000B 
      28 0015  EE            OUT DX,AL 
      29                 
      30 0016  B9 00FF           MOV cx, 0ffH 
      31 0019  E2 FE            D1: LOOP D1 
adc.asm(31): error A2062: Missing or unreachable CS
      32 001B  BA 0002             MOV DX, PORTB 
      33 001E  B0 01             MOV AL, 00000001B 
      34 0020  EE            OUT DX,AL 
      35                           
      36 0021  B9 00FF                     MOV cx, 0ffH 
      37 0024  E2 FE            D2: LOOP D2 
adc.asm(37): error A2062: Missing or unreachable CS
      38 0026  EB E0             JMP XX 
      39                 
      40 0028               CODE ENDS 
      41                END 
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 5.00                  1/5/23 20:55:25
                                                             Symbols-1


Segments and Groups:

                N a m e             Length   Align  Combine Class

CODE . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    0028    PARA    NONE    
DATA . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    0000    PARA    NONE    

Symbols:            

                N a m e             Type     Value   Attr

D1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    L NEAR  0019    CODE
D2 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    L NEAR  0024    CODE

PORTA  . . . . . . . . . . . . .    NUMBER  0000    
PORTB  . . . . . . . . . . . . .    NUMBER  0002    
PORTC  . . . . . . . . . . . . .    NUMBER  0004    
PORT_CON . . . . . . . . . . . .    NUMBER  0006    

START  . . . . . . . . . . . . .    L NEAR  0000    CODE

XX . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    L NEAR  0008    CODE

@FILENAME  . . . . . . . . . . .    TEXT  adc       


     41 Source  Lines
     41 Total   Lines
     12 Symbols

  50730 + 465814 Bytes symbol space free

      0 Warning Errors
      4 Severe  Errors
```

Comment: Since you aren't using the simplified DOS models and defining your segments then you are going to have to tell MASM which segments to assume CS and DS. Add `ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA`  to the top of the code (preferably just after `CODE SEGMENT`)